# Retrieve image from database and display using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm facing problem while retrieving image location from database and display it using ajax. 
Below is the code.
I can retrieve all the data except image.
Needed help with that please.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "http://localhost/project/app/read.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            var id = field.id;
            var bookname = field.bookname;
            var publisher = field.publisher;
            var author = field.author;
            var location = field.location; //image location
            $("#listview").append("<h2>" + bookname + " </h2><p>" + publisher + "</p><p>" + author + "</p>");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**read.php**

```
    <?php
include "db.php";
$data=array();
$q=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `book`");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
 $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**the below code is also not working**

```
"<img src=" +location+ /">"
```

Comment: show us the return and the read.php codes

Comment: where is the code that appends the image: there should be some `"<img src="+location+ /">" ` somewhere?